# Call of Duty Black Ops Zombies (iOS) glitches when paused or exiting the app?

Tags: ios, cod-black-ops-zombies-mobile

I have been playing CoD mobile for a while now, on my iPod 4th gen fine (until it died) and I got the 5th gen iPod IOS9. The game play is better but whenever I  pause the game, or save/exit the app, it almost always glitches the entire game.

What I mean is any zombies on the map end up phasing through walls, walking out of the map and any that spawn don't move from their spawn point, so I get stuck unable to kill any zombies and I have to frustratingly restart the game again.

Is there a way to fix this issue?